# Free chemical database to search for physical properties?

Tags: physical-chemistry, computational-chemistry, reference-request

I am looking for an Open-access tool that can search "backwards", eg. give me all the structures corresponding to a given heat of formation, critical pressure, etc. It would be even better if the database canbe automatically searched by API or by downloading it. Currently my best go is [ChemExper](https://www.chemexper.com), where I can search for some of the properties, but it is challenging to make it automatic. Is there anything similar in the field?

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/22285/public-api-for-physical-properties

Answer (score 4):

As I've mentioned on other related questions, this is very much an open topic. There aren't many open-access databases in chemistry, and far fewer that have APIs.

- As suggested in the other answer, there are multiple ways to query / scrape Wikipedia.
- [ChemSpider](http://www.chemspider.com/FullSearch.aspx) offers some property search features.
- [Reaxys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaxys) offers some property searching, including spectra features. It's not open access.

Comment: Indeed, what I see is open access chemistry databases have a long way to go. The reason I asked this question is exactly this: there might be some databases that slipped my knowledge. On an open forum like stackechange, there might be someone who knows something.

Comment: @Ezze I think it's a good question. It's just not that different from the [last question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/22285/public-api-for-physical-properties?lq=1)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't see the question. However, I am hoping for a better answer this time.

Comment: @Ezze - Nothing has changed since then. In a few months, we'll be rolling out API-based property search for [PQR](https://pqr.pitt.edu/) but these would be computed values.

Answer (score 3):

You might search the German Wikipedia using SPARQL via [DBpedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBpedia).

Go to http://de.dbpedia.org/sparql and run your query, e.g.

```
PREFIX dbo:<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?chem ?bp
{
  ?chem a dbo:ChemicalSubstance .
  ?chem dbo:boilingPoint ?bp .
  FILTER ((?bp >= 372) && (?bp <= 374))
}
ORDER BY ?bp
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just discovered [this website](http://www.crct.polymtl.ca/FACT/index.php?websites=1) where you can find a tremendous amount of data, especially about inorganic chemistry with things like E-pH diagrams, phase-diagrams, things about alloys of different metals, ultra pure silicone, salts, elements, nuclear data and so on.

And if you prefer sugar derivatives [here](http://www.sugartech.co.za/matlprop/) is a great database with online calculators about many sugar things, syrops etc.

Enjoy !!!